# Instagram Basic Display API, can we skip the "Save Your Login Info? step?

Tags: instagram-api

Using the Instagram Basic Display API, is there a way to have the oauth log-in process skip the "Save Your Login Info?" step? That screen has links to many pages where the users of our application are not allowed to access. We have a kiosk application that is using Instagram Basic Display API to allow the user to retrieve their Instagram images. The user should not be allowed to visit their feed or many of the other links on that screen.